# Looking for the right way to rename the GRUB boot entries

Tags: grub2

I am taking about the naming of existing/default GRUB boot entry. Currently I've the following options at GRUB screen:

```
Trisquel GNU/Linux
Advanced options for Trisquel GNU/Linux
Trisquel GNU/Linux, with Linux-Libre 3.13.0-39-lowlatency (recovery mode)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
Edubuntu ISO
```

Where First three entries are default with Trisquel GNU/Linux, 4<sup>th</sup> is for Windows boot loader and 5<sup>th</sup> is custom entry defined at `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.Now suppose I want to change the name/text of say 4<sup>th</sup> entry `Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)`, then which is the right way?

I found above menu entries at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Example for that I want to change:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-0A7072DF7072D145' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0A7072DF7072D145
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0A7072DF7072D145
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

So, Can I safely replace the name/text `'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)'` with which I want and then `update-grub2`?

Briefly I want to know How do I change the name of GRUB boot entry?

Comment: If you want custom entries then the right way is to use `40_custom` for all your entries. You then disable the other files (`chmod -x` them with the exception of `00_header` and then run `update-grub` or whatever it's called on your distro).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly, but this file gets overwritten by `update-grub2`. If your configuration does not change often, this may be the easiest way for you.

Or take a look at:

- [Grub 2 Title Tweaks Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287602)
- [Grub Customizer package Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183#post10340183)

Alternatively have a look at this folder `/etc/grub.d`. From there `update-grub2` generates the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

---

You can change the way the auto-generation labels the Windows entries, especially as you only got one Windows installed, by overwriting the specific menuentry command in the `30_os-prober` script.

Go to `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` and look for `menuentry '$(echo "${LONGNAME} $onstr" | grub_quote)' --class windows ...`. Replace the `' '` part with your label, but keep the other options the same.

e.g. on my system:`menuentry 'My Windows 7 system' --class windows --class os \$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-$(grub_get_device_id "${DEVICE}")' {
EOF`

But there is a catch to that: firstly there are two of these entries in `30_os-prober`: one for `chain)`, another for `efi)`, thus you should change both. Secondly **I guess** these changes will be overwritten, once there is an update to these files / to grub.

---

Another approach:

You can disable the windows part in the `30_os-prober` script by commenting `#` those `menuentry ...`commands in the windows sections `chain)` and `efi)`. That will remove the auto-generated windows entry. Then take your current windows bootentry from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and copy it into the custom menu file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.