# grub-mkconfig - one Linux kernel, multiple boot entries with different kernel options

Tags: grub, grub2-mkconfig

GRUB version: 2.04-20

One Linux kernel only; I need to have two GRUB entries to boot the kernel with different set of kernel options. For the time being, after each `grub-mkconfig` or `update-grub2` which produces one entry with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` options, I manually add another one with the different set.

Is there any way to get two entries of the same kernel with different kernel options (one respecting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` plus another one) after running `grub-mkconfig` or `update-grub2`? I suppose some custom script in `/etc/grub.d`?

Added bonus, proper way to disable `os-prober`? For the time being, I've renamed `os-prober` script so that it's not found.

Comment: This will disable os-prober (add to `/etc/default/grub`): `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true`.

Answer (score 0):

to get two grub menu entries at boot, those are defined in (Redhat for example) `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`

in your `grub.cfg` you will see `menuentry {...}` where the open & close curly braces are separated by around 15 lines.  But each menuentry corresponds to what you see in the grub boot menu at boot time.  They normally correspond to the last 5 or so kernel versions.

Simply edit this file and clone your menu entry of interest then modify the kernel options you wish, and adjust the menu entry title accordingly so you can pick it when the grub boot menu show up.

Like was said for the `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"` that you put in `/etc/default/grub` then when you run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` (on redhat for example) then that `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` is modified and that's where everything happens.  Don't run `grub2-mkconfig` after manually editing the `/boot/efi/.../grub.cfg` file otherwise you'll undo your custom menu entry.  I'm not a grub2 expert, I know just enough to be dangerous and kinda point you to the correct location.  Is there a better way to manage grub menu entries, like a high level elegant way like what `/etc/default/grub` is I don't know I've never researched enough.  These may help:

[Looking for the right way to rename the GRUB boot entries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/looking-for-the-right-way-to-rename-the-grub-boot-entries)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove

and it would be the **linuxefi** line from a given menu entry, such as:

```
linuxefi /vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=800e924a-a869-4152-9503-9d9cfecbd16e ro verbose fips=1 boot=UUID=4f3da85a-71a9-4f6e-bc5f-dfd23a880b08 modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0
```

my `/etc/default/grub` has exactly `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="verbose fips=1 boot=UUID=4f3da85a-71a9-4f6e-bc5f-dfd23a880b08 modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0"`

so just modify those corresponding parameters.

Comment: sorry if it's not clear in the question: I'm currently adding the entry I need exactly the way you suggest; what I need is to be done automatically. So that I don't need to re-add it whenever kernel is updated (grub2-mkconfig is invoked automatically in that case, and it's the proper thing to do).

Comment: for having it done and retained automatically, when you figure that out you let me know I'd be interested  :)

Comment: maybe this... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62733/how-to-correctly-set-up-the-right-grub-2-default-menu-entry